# Accessing private variable from test and completing the coverage functionality

Tags: java, unit-testing, dao, private-members

I have a class called FilterSite that has a instance variable of type UserDao. Because the userDao variable is only used inside this class, i made it as private.

When testing, i am setting this private userDao via a setter method. UserDao fetches data from database and is used in filterData().

```
class FilterSite {
 @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

   public void filterData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   User user = userDao.findByUsername(request.getParameter("username")
     if( user != null && request.getParameter("site").equalsIgnoreCase(user.getSite())) {
         //do something
    }
   }

 public void setUserDao(UserDao dao) {
        this.userDao = dao;
   }
    }
```

I have a test class called TestFilterSite, which creates a random userDao and sets FilterSite class userDao.

```
public class TestFilterSite {
    @Mock
    UserDao userDao;

@Before
        public void setup(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            Mockito.when(userDao.findByUsername(validUsername)).thenReturn(createUser());


               User user = userDao.findByUsername(validUsername);
                Assert.assertEquals(validUsername,user.getUsername());
                Assert.assertEquals(validPassword,user.getPassword());
                Mockito.verify(userDao).findByUsername(validUsername);
            }

      @Test
      public void testFilterSiteWhenBlankSiteIsProvided(){
        FilterSite filterSite = new FilterSite();
        filterSite.setUserDao(userDao);
        filterSite.filterData(MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpServletResponse);
        //assert responses

      }
        }
```

After reading some articles, i found that i should not use getters/setters for private variables when writing a test class. 
So, how do i write test for this class?

Comment: *After reading some articles,* please provide links

Answer (score -1):

You can use Getter/Setter wherever required. You can you OpenPoJo library for  test coverage of your getter/setter methods.

https://github.com/OpenPojo/openpojo/wiki